# Can't start while loop with networkstream.read()

Tags: c#, while-loop, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I am writing small console app which sends file content in a base64 format over TCP. As it seems I can't send the data at once, so I am trying to make a while loop which receives all the data from NetworkStream, but I am always getting this exception while doing it:

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote hostat System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)   at File_Transfer_Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Files from PC\Visual Basic Projects - =&+Ivan+&=\Tesseract\Temp\File Transfer\File_Transfer_Server\Program.cs:line 31
```

This is my client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace File_Transfer_Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6666);

            NetworkStream clientNetworkStream = client.GetStream();

            string fileContent = FileBase64Encoding(@"D:\Download\AtomSetup-x64.exe");

                        byte[] fileBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileContent);
                        byte[] fileLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileBytes.Length.ToString());

            clientNetworkStream.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Send");
        }

        static string FileBase64Encoding(string path)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            string fileBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

            return fileBase64String;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my server code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace File_Transfer_Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener serverListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 6666);
            serverListener.Start();
            TcpClient tcpClient = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine(">>> Receiving");

            byte[] clientBuffer = new byte[1024];

            using (NetworkStream clientNStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {

                int i;
                string received = "";
                string data = null;


                while ((i = clientNStream.Read(clientBuffer, 0, clientBuffer.Length)) != 0) // exception 
                {
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientBuffer, 0, i);

                    received += data;
                }
                File.WriteAllText(@"E:\receivedData.txt", received);
                Console.WriteLine(">>>Done");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I tried almost any solution, including memory streams but nothing worked for me.
I will appreciate any help without being judged too much.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wich line throws the exception? Please mark it with a comment in your text.

Comment: @Christopher, I edited it. You can see the exception comment in the server code.

Comment: So, your client code calls `Write` (which on return just means that the local OS will send the data, not that it necessarily *has*), displays a message on the console, then exits and forcibly tears down its connection rather than doing a clean shutdown on it. I'd look to fix that first (and side note, I'd look at why you're encoding and re-encoding so many times - if you want to send an arbitrary file, why not just send its bytes directly over the stream rather than Base64 encoding it?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the Base64 encoding is part of my assignment for this small project.